# how to update azure vm firewall inbound port rules using python

Tags: python, azure, automation, firewall

[image]I want to bind/update/white listing my IP address in inbound port rules using python(automate).

I went through this [url](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/network-python-manage-loadbalancer/blob/master/example.py)! and what 
I understood

```py
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'],
        secret=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        tenant=os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
    )
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)


# Create VNet
    print('Create Vnet')
    async_vnet_creation = network_client.virtual_networks.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        VNET_NAME,
        {
            'location': LOCATION,
            'address_space': {
                'address_prefixes': ['10.0.0.0/16']
            }
        }
    )
    async_vnet_creation.wait()

    # Create Subnet
    async_subnet_creation = network_client.subnets.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        VNET_NAME,
        SUBNET_NAME,
        {'address_prefix': '10.0.0.0/24'}
    )
    subnet_info = async_subnet_creation.result()

    # Creating NIC
    print('Creating NetworkInterface 1')

    back_end_address_pool_id = lb_info.backend_address_pools[0].id

    inbound_nat_rule_1_id = lb_info.inbound_nat_rules[0].id
    async_nic1_creation = network_client.network_interfaces.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        VMS_INFO[1]['nic_name'],
        create_nic_parameters(
            subnet_info.id, back_end_address_pool_id, inbound_nat_rule_1_id)
    )

    inbound_nat_rule_2_id = lb_info.inbound_nat_rules[1].id
    print('Creating NetworkInterface 2')
    async_nic2_creation = network_client.network_interfaces.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        VMS_INFO[2]['nic_name'],
        create_nic_parameters(
            subnet_info.id, back_end_address_pool_id, inbound_nat_rule_2_id)
    )

    nic1_info = async_nic1_creation.result()
    nic2_info = async_nic2_creation.result()
```

But I didn't find a place to add ip which I want to whitelisting.
please help on this 
or please tell how to whitelist my IP using python azure SDK ?

Comment: Do you mean the firewall in the vnet or the NSG rules?

Comment: @CharlesXu I have updated my question with a reference picture  , please go through it.

Comment: Is that you want to create inbound rule in you NSG group with python? Is that right?

Comment: @JimXu yes. Can you help me ?

Comment: @Pradiptadas Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new inbound rule for an existing NSG, you can use the following script:

```
    from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
    from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
    from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
    from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup
    from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import SecurityRule
    from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient

    subscription_id = 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx',
        secret = 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx',
        tenant = 'xxxxxx-xxxxxxx'
    )

    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
        credentials,
        subscription_id
    )

    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
        credentials,
        subscription_id
    )

    resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Network')

    resource_group_name = 'test-rg'


    async_security_rule = network_client.security_rules.create_or_update(
    resource_group_name,
    security_group_name,
    new_security_rule_name,
    {
            'access':azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models.SecurityRuleAccess.allow,
            'description':'New Test security rule',
            'destination_address_prefix':'*',
            'destination_port_range':'123-3500',
            'direction':azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models.SecurityRuleDirection.inbound,
            'priority':400,
            'protocol':azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models.SecurityRuleProtocol.tcp,
            'source_address_prefix':'*',
            'source_port_range':'655',
    }
)

security_rule = async_security_rule.result()
```

For more details, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.operations.securityrulesoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--network-security-group-name--security-rule-name--security-rule-parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false--polling-true----operation-config-)

Comment: great I'm gonna definitely try it

Comment: can you please clarify these variables, please ?
self.group_name, security_group_name, new_security_rule_name

Comment: please help me to understand these variables also **_destination_port_range_**
,  **_source_port_range_**

Comment: @Pradiptadasp Regarding the issue, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.operations.securityrulesoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--network-security-group-name--security-rule-name--security-rule-parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false--polling-true----operation-config-)

Comment: @Pradiptadas self.group_name : your resource group name,  security_group_name: your NSG  name, new_security_rule_name : the inbound rule name.

Comment: ```python

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 40, in <module>
    'access':azure.mgmt.network.models.SecurityRuleAccess.allow,
AttributeError: module 'azure.mgmt.network' has no attribute 'models'
```
I am getting this issue @JimXu

Comment: Could you please try to use ```azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models.SecurityRuleAccess.allow```?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly. But didn't meet my requirement. 
how to add IP address in **Source IP addresses/CIDR ranges**

Comment: You can update the ```source_address_prefix``` as your need.

Comment: Yes, I figured out, what if I want to add multiple, would I use a loop ?

Comment: You can update the ```source_address_prefix ```  as ```10.0.0.0/16, 192.188.1.0/32``` to add multiple IP

Comment: _source_address_prefix_ field takes only **string** type data

Comment: Have you tried use ```'10.0.0.0/16,192.188.1.0/32'```?

Comment: Regarding the issue, please use the latest sdk. In the lates sdk, source_address_prefix type is list. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2019_09_01.models.securityrule?view=azure-python